# Docker Copy seems buggy

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-build

So I am trying to make a simple docker container to run `sabnzbd` in a container.

I do a git clone and then move `sabnzbd` folder into container.

Note: When I look in `sabnzbd`, all files look ok so it's not a git problem or branch etc. I'm happy so far there.

When I then run the container, I double checked but half the files are missing. For example, I was looking to make sure `cheerypy` was copied but it wasn't, and yes, i can confirm that I double checked again in `sabnzbd` folder.

So I have a folder with Dockerfile and `sabnzbd`. I built from that folder with the command:

```
sudo docker build --no-cache=true -t sabnzbd -f Dockerfile .
```

In a nutshell, the only thing that worked was `Copy . /`

I tried `COPY sabnzbd/* sabnzbd` and other variations.

I originally thought it was getting files from elsewhere but removed any trace of `sabnzbd`, but for my understanding it only looks at files relative to the docker build file.

I just thought this was so soo weird and wanted to get some thoughts even though I fixed it. I did remove all images and started from scratch but result was the same.

I did try the `no cache` option with build but still the same.

Thoughts?

Comment: Have a look at `https://hub.docker.com/search/?isAutomated=0&isOfficial=0&page=1&pullCount=0&q=Sabnzbd&starCount=0`

Comment: Whats this for and it didnt work actually, as in no link

Comment: Please provide an http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve